# Am I able to submit packages with a file?

Tags: python, matplotlib

I'm trying to turn in a project for a class. I want to use a package for the project such as matplotlib and create a user friendly graph program.

```
import matplotlib as grp
```

My question is, when my professor opens the Python file, will he be able to see the graph?

Comment: Does he have matplotlib installed? It's not part of the default Python install.

Comment: Probably not. Does that mean he won't be able to see it?

Comment: Yes. As an alternative, have you considered saving the graph as an image?

Answer (score 0):

Well first of all it is fairly easy to install additional packages in Python using pip. If he got matplotlib installed he will see it.

Alternatively if you are unsure you can use pip to install the package locally inside your project directory.

`pip install matplotlib --target ./matplotlib`

This is going to install matplotlib in the subdirectory /matplotlib which you can then include in your code.